# Cannot load library: load_library[1098]: Library '/system/lib/libhoudini.so' not found

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

[Писал на SO тоже](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47037631/caused-by-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cannot-load-library-load-library109).

Обновил `Android Studio` до 3.0.0 и `Gradle plugin` до 3.0.0 (Gradle 4.1)

После запуска своего приложения на эмуляторе Genymotion (устройства с API 16-19) оно падает на первой строке (объявлении класса) стартовой Activity (`at com.myapp.start.StartActivity.<init>(StartActivity.java:40)`).

**Error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                      at android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity.<init>(SupportActivity.java:68)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityGingerbread.<init>(BaseFragmentActivityGingerbread.java:37)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.<init>(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:29)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.<init>(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:30)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.<init>(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.<init>(AppCompatActivity.java:61)
                      at com.myapp.start.BaseActivity.<init>(BaseActivity.java:37)
                      at com.myapp.start.StartActivity.<init>(StartActivity.java:40)
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                   Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: load_library[1098]: Library '/system/lib/libhoudini.so' not found
```

Нативные методы не использую. Как выход установил `ndk` через `sdk Manager`. Все равно - `Cannot load library: load_library[1098]: Library '/system/lib/libhoudini.so' not found`

Два дня потратил уже на поиски. В чем может быть проблема?

Что за `libhoudini.so`? Где эта библиотека должна быть? Папка system - Windows system?

Comment: Попробуйте установить Genymotion-ARM-Translation в Genymotion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Помог добрый человек](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47322145/5330439)

Перейти в Run-->Edit Configurations.. --> Profiling Tab --> Uncheck (Enable advanced profiling)

Переписал (понизил) в `build.gradle(Module: app)` минимальную версию `minSdkVersion SDK`, так как пришлось ограничить `21`-ой и заработало.

Answer (score 1):

`libhoudini.so` - библиотека поддержки процессоров ARM в GenyMotion.

Раньше он шел в комплекте с Google Play в GenyMotion, потом его почему-то выпилили оттуда.

[Почитайте здесь](https://koreanrandom.com/forum/topic/13409-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-arm-translation-%D0%B8-google-play-apps-%D0%B2-genymotion/) способ ее установки.

Comment: На прежней версии Android Studio (2.3) с прежней версией Gradle (3.4.1) такой проблемы не возникало. По инструкции установил. Все равно крашится приложение. Google Apps не появились. Эмулировал Nexus 4 - 4.4.4 - API 19. Интересно что на эмулируемых устройствах >21 API все нормально.